# VSCode does not autocomplete Node.JS modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, editor

That's how it works with default js methods, IntelliSense seems to understand and autocomplete this
[image]

And when I'm trying to import some node default modules (path,fs,http)
This highlighting does not show methods of these objects, how can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Probably not of any help, but on my machine the snippet from your last screenshot just works and gives me intellisense for the `path` namespace...

Comment: Please mention vs code version

Comment: did you install the packages ? make sure `node_modules` exist, run `npm install`

Comment: Do you have node and npm installed? VS Code uses npm to automatically download the types that power intellisense. See [this section of the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition) for mode info

Answer (score 6):

If you have `tsconfig.json` for some reason, add `enableAutoDiscovery` to true, as it default to false if that file exists.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    ...
    "typingOptions": {
      "enableAutoDiscovery": true
    }
}
```